# SQL Server - Getting initials from a list of names

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table containing a list of employees assigned to a certain project. A bit like this :

```
ID  Employees
122 Mark Doe
210 John Doe
212 Julie Doe, Yuri Doe
```

I have to transform the Employees column to get the initial of the first name and get the full last name. The result should look like this :

```
ID  Employees
122 M. Doe
210 J. Doe
212 J. Doe, Y. Doe
```

Problem occurs when the value contains more then one name. What can be done for this?

Comment: This would be a very simple task if you had properly designed your schema. The problem with bad design is the hoops you have to jump through in order to get anything done.

Comment: I suggest fixing your design first, then worry about presentation.

Comment: You need two columns `FirstName` and `LastName`, and the row with two names should be split into two rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for PostgreSQL. Assuming that the multiple names in a cell are consistently separated by a comma and a following space you could

1 expand all multi name cells into separate rows

2 split the column with the names into separate columns representing first name and last name

3 extract first letter from the first name and join it with the last name

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id int, employee VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO employees (id, employee)
VALUES 
(122, 'Mark Doe'),
(210, 'John Doe'),
(212, 'Julie Doe, Yuri Doe');
 
 SELECT
 id
 ,left(split_part(firs_last_name,' ',1),1) || '. ' || split_part(firs_last_name,' ',2) 
 as  wanted_name
 ,split_part(firs_last_name,' ',1) as first_name
 ,split_part(firs_last_name,' ',2) as last_name
 FROM
   (
   Select 
   id, unnest(string_to_array(employee, ', ')) as firs_last_name
    FROM employees
   ) s
```

```
|  id | wanted_name | first_name | last_name |
|-----|-------------|------------|-----------|
| 122 |      M. Doe |       Mark |       Doe |
| 210 |      J. Doe |       John |       Doe |
| 212 |      J. Doe |      Julie |       Doe |
| 212 |      Y. Doe |       Yuri |       Doe |
```

if you want to have the multiple names in the cells back, you can aggraegate them in the final step

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id int, employee VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO employees (id, employee)
VALUES 
(122, 'Mark Doe'),
(210, 'John Doe'),
(212, 'Julie Doe, Yuri Doe');
 
 with transformed_names as 
 (SELECT
 id
 ,left(split_part(firs_last_name,' ',1),1) || '. ' || 
  split_part(firs_last_name,' ',2)  as  wanted_name
 ,split_part(firs_last_name,' ',1) as first_name
 ,split_part(firs_last_name,' ',2) as last_name
 FROM
   (
   Select 
   id ,unnest(string_to_array(employee, ', ')) as firs_last_name
   FROM employees
   ) s)

SELECT
id
, string_agg(wanted_name, ', ') as wanted_names  
from transformed_names
GROUP BY 
id

|  id |     string_agg |
|-----|----------------|
| 122 |         M. Doe |
| 210 |         J. Doe |
| 212 | J. Doe, Y. Doe |
```

but then again it is all depending on clean consistent data in your table